# Django Tabular in Line example

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I really need somebody to explain/show me how I can achieve a `TabularInline` display in the **django admin** console of my example. Could somebody help me out?

My models are as follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.player_name)

class MatchdayStats(models.Model):
    MATCHDAY_STATS_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    appeared = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    goal = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minutes_under_60 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    minutes_60 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assist =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.MATCHDAY_STATS_ID)

class PlayerGameweekStats(models.Model):
    PLAYER_GAMEWEEK_ALLSTATS_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    gameweek = models.ForeignKey('fixturesresults.Gameweek')
    matchday_stats = models.ForeignKey(MatchdayStats)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (gw=%s,msid=%s)' % (self.player.player_name,self.gameweek.GAMEWEEK_ID,self.matchday_stats.MATCHDAY_STATS_ID)
```

I would like there to be a tabular display for the PlayerGameweekStats model, where you can enter `MatchdayStats` fields for each player.

The admin code below causes a Foreign Key error `<class 'playerteamstats.models.MatchdayStats'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'playerteamstats.models.PlayerGameweekStats'>`

```
class StatsInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MatchdayStats

class PlayerGameweekStatsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('player', 'gameweek')
    exclude = ('gameweek')
    inlines = [
        StatsInLine,
    ]

admin.site.register(PlayerGameweekStats, PlayerGameweekStatsAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

To build TabularInline models need to be connected with ForeignKey.
From Django docs [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline):

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

In you case you need to have ForeignKey to PlayerGameweekStats in MatchdayStats.

Comment: But how could this be achieved if I cant change the foreign key? :/